# Rails 4. Attribute not saving when creating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes

I am stumped as to why this isn't working. I have a review system, and a link to create a new review passing 2 attributes; user_id and gigid. Both id's are being generated as integers but when I save the review, the gigid saves as 'nil' rather than the integer.

View:

```
<%= link_to 'Click here to rate this user', new_user_review_path(:user_id => request.user.id, :gigid => request.gig.id) %>
```

Here both ID's are set correctly (according to server output). User_id is the user which is to be reviewed (works correctly) and gigid is a reference for post validation. (works correctly until I try and save)

_form :

```
<%= simple_form_for([@user, @user.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
<div id="rating-form">
<label>Rating</label>
</div>
<%= f.input :comment %>
<%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
def new
    if user_signed_in?
    @review = current_user.reviews.new
  else
    redirect_to(root_url)
    flash[:danger] = "You must log in to rate a user"
  end
  end

def create
    @review = @user.reviews.new review_params
    @review.reviewed_id = current_user.id
       if @review.save
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

private

    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment, :gigid, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Server output when clicking link:

```
Started GET "/users/21/reviews/new?gigid=17&locale=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-13 18:08:26 +0100
Processing by ReviewsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"gigid"=>"17", "locale"=>"en", "user_id"=>"21"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 21]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered reviews/_form.html.erb (4.9ms)
```

I then add a comment and a rating and click create.
Server output when clicking create:

```
Started POST "/users/21/reviews?locale=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-13 18:10:44 +0100
Processing by ReviewsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"RToZwvodvXxQp1/spEhgemO/oi+4rof8jREuLw27CcEsEBqFWGLeYne1CgH3kvWu9OzAV+bHvOk9g9nq8JMPnw==", "review"=>{"rating"=>"5", "comment"=>"sdfsdfdd"}, "commit"=>"Create Review", "locale"=>"en", "user_id"=>"21"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 21]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "reviews" ("rating", "comment", "user_id", "reviewed_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["rating", 5], ["comment", "sdfsdfdd"], ["user_id", 21], ["reviewed_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-01-13 17:10:44.675386"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-13 17:10:44.675386"]]
   (93.6ms)  commit transaction
```

I notice that 'gigid' is being completely ignored here, but EVERYTHING else saves fine.
I don't understand why one attribute saves and the other doesn't, any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the form code?

Comment: I am using link_to instead of a form. The first bit of quoted code is the code I'm using.

Comment: where is the `#new` action code?

Comment: I mean the form that you are used to post attribute values to the db.

Comment: Post your `_form.html.erb` code.

Comment: added #new and _form. Everything saves fine apart from gigid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form doesn't have anything for `gigid` to send it to `create` action. You can use hidden field in the form like below

```
<%= simple_form_for([@user, @user.reviews.build]) do |f| %>
  <div id="rating-form">
    <label>Rating</label>
  </div>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.input :gigid, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => params[:gigid] }
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have tried this and get: undefined method `gig' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x007f540b2bafa0>. The :gigid => request.gig.id doesn't get passed to the create form

Comment: If I manually enter a number then this does work and gigid saves correctly but i cant pass the request.gig.id to the form. I don't think I can retrieve that specific gig.id from within this form.

Comment: adding params[:gigid] as the value as @kimrgrey pointed out has fixed this for me. In the end my hidden field reads as '<%= f.input :gigid, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => params[:gigid] } %>
'

Answer (score 0):

There is no `gigid` in review params. Look carefully on your params when you are performing POST: `"review"=>{"rating"=>"5", "comment"=>"sdfsdfdd"}`. Just review and comment. And after it you are doing:

```
params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment, :gigid, :user_id)
```

Comment: This is what I'm confused about. I set user_id and gigid in the same fashion, but only user_id saves. On my form I dont have an input for either, as they need to be set on creation

Comment: Not in the same. You have a form which was created for the @user object, but you didn't put information about `gigid ` in this form. Just add hidden field and everything will work.

Comment: Thanks, manually entering a number into the hidden field allows the gigid to be saved, but I need a way to send the gig ID from the previous page into the form.

Comment: You have `gigid` from previous page in params when you are doing get request on `/new`. Just use value from `params[:gigid]` as value for hidden field.

Comment: Yes yes yes that's it. I wasn't sure how to pass that value to the form.            <%= f.input :gigid, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => params[:gigid] } %> is working for me. Thanks.